# Passing an array of JSON objects to laravel

Tags: jquery, json, laravel

So I have an array containing many JSON objects, This is what it shows in console.log if i output my array:

```
{"data" :[{"line":"1","band":"X","val":"0"},{"line":"1","band":"A","val":"6461"},{"line":"1","band":"B","val":"6896"},{"line":"1","band":"C","val":"5826"},{"line":"1","band":"D","val":"3704"},{"line":"1","band":"E","val":"2141"},{"line":"1","band":"F","val":"1198"},{"line":"1","band":"G","val":"682"},{"line":"1","band":"H","val":"70"},{"line":"2","band":"X","val":"0"},{"line":"2","band":"A","val":"87"},{"line":"2","band":"B","val":"65"},{"line":"2","band":"C","val":"48"},{"line":"2","band":"D","val":"35"},{"line":"2","band":"E","val":"12"},{"line":"2","band":"F","val":"14"},{"line":"2","band":"G","val":"4"},{"line":"2","band":"H","val":"0"},{"line":"3","band":"X","val":"0"},{"line":"3","band":"A","val":"0"},{"line":"3","band":"B","val":"0"},{"line":"3","band":"C","val":"0"},{"line":"3","band":"D","val":"0"},{"line":"3","band":"E","val":"0"},{"line":"3","band":"F","val":"0"},{"line":"3","band":"G","val":"0"},{"line":"3","band":"H","val":"0"}]}
```

returnObj is outputted above. This is how i build the array to post back to laravel

```
$('table tr td input').each(function()
{               
    Obj = 
    {           
        line : $(this).parent().attr('line'),
        band : $(this).parent().attr('band'),
        val : $(this).val()
    }

    returnObj.push(Obj);

});

returnObject =  '{"data" :' + JSON.stringify(returnObj) +'}';
console.log(returnObject);
```

This is my ajax on the page:

```
$.ajax({ 
type: "POST", 
url: "magic/whatif", 
data : returnObject
}) 
.done(function(response) 
{ 
    alert(response); 
});
```

There is no problem with my routes or logic, I simply print_r or echo the data that was passed in as the response so i can see what laravel does with it.

```
$data = Input::all(); 
print_r($data);
```

The problem is laravel can not handle the array of objects so it sends back this:

```
Array ( [undefined] => )
```

There are many solutions and I had it working when you just pass a single JSON object to laravel but i need to pass an array containing many JSON objects to laravel from the view.

Comment: You need to stringify the object before you send it e.g. `data: { returnObject: JSON.stringify(returnObject) }`. It looks like you're using php, so you should be able to get the data with `json_decode($_GET['returnObject'], true)`. The laravel syntax seems to be `Input::get('returnObject');`

Comment: I have tried that already ofc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following line:

```
returnObject =  '{"data" :' + JSON.stringify(returnObj) +'}';
```

To this:

```
returnObject =  { returnObj : returnObj };
```

You may access that data using:

```
$data = Input::get('returnObj');
```

Output (Dump and Die):

```
dd($data);
```